# Android App shows wrong output since second run

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to Android Development and I made an app for solving sudoku puzzle. Whenever I freshly install the app or force stop the app and start it again, it works fine. But if I try to run the app once more without stopping it, it gives wrong output.
Here's my code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText[] arr=new EditText[9];
    Button submitButton;
    char[][] board;
    TextView[] ret=new TextView[9];
    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        arr[0]=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.e1);
        arr[1]=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.e2);
        arr[2]=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.e3);
        arr[3]=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.e4);
        arr[4]=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.e5);
        arr[5]=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.e6);
        arr[6]=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.e7);
        arr[7]=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.e8);
        arr[8]=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.e9);
        ret[0]=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.o1);
        ret[1]=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.o2);
        ret[2]=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.o3);
        ret[3]=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.o4);
        ret[4]=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.o5);
        ret[5]=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.o6);
        ret[6]=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.o7);
        ret[7]=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.o8);
        ret[8]=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.o9);
        board=new char[9][0];
        submitButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.submit_button);
        submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                for(int i=0;i<9;++i)
                    board[i]=arr[i].getText().toString().toCharArray();
                Solve.solveSudoku(board);
                for(int i=0;i<9;++i)
                    ret[i].setText(new String(board[i]));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The logic of solution is the backtracking algorithm which checks all possible  numbers for a particular box in the grid.
Here's code to that:

```
package com.example.sudokusolver;

public class Solve {

    public static boolean flag =false;
    public static void dfs(int k,int[][] arr,int[] r,int[] c,int[] box,int count,char [][] board,int[][] index)
    {
        if(k==count)
            flag=true;
        else
        {
            int i=arr[k][0],j=arr[k][1];
            for(int n=0;n<9;++n)
            {
                int val=1<<n;
                if(((r[i]&val)==0)&&((c[j]&val)==0)&&((box[index[i][j]]&val)==0))
                {
                    r[i]|=val;
                    c[j]|=val;
                    box[index[i][j]]|=val;
                    board[i][j]=(char)('1'+n);
                    dfs(k+1,arr,r,c,box,count,board,index);
                    if(flag)
                        return;
                    r[i]&=~(val);
                    c[j]&=~(val);
                    box[index[i][j]]&=~(val);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public static void solveSudoku(char[][] board)
    {
        int [][] index=new int[9][9];
        int[] dx= new int[] {0,3,6};
        int count=0;
        for(int r:dx)
            for(int c:dx)
            {
                for(int i=0;i<3;++i)
                    for(int j=0;j<3;++j)
                        index[r+i][c+j]=count;
                ++count;
            }
        int[] r=new int[9];
        int[] c=new int[9];
        int[] box=new int[9];
        int[][] arr=new int[81][0];
        count=0;
        for(int i=0;i<9;++i)
            for(int j=0;j<9;++j)
                if(board[i][j]!='0')
                {
                    int val=1<<(board[i][j]-'1');
                    r[i]=r[i]|val;
                    box[index[i][j]]=box[index[i][j]]|val;
                    c[j]=c[j]|val;
                }
                else
                    arr[count++]=new int[]{i,j};
        dfs(0,arr,r,c,box,count,board,index);

    }
}
```

Comment: Please Add your code and logic here in Question

Comment: As already said, it's really difficult to say what's happening without seeing any of your code. That said, it could be that you're not reinitializing the variables correctly at some point

Comment: I have add the code, please check now